# Cisco ASA syslog format description

Tags: cisco-asa, syslog

Where can I find Cisco ASA syslog format description? Log example:

```
Dec 11 08:01:24 <IP> %ASA-6-302015: Built outbound UDP connection 447235 for outside:NTP_Server_2/<port> (NTP_Server_2/<port>) to identity:<IP>/<port> (<IP>/<port>)
Dec 11 08:01:24 <IP> %ASA-6-302015: Built outbound UDP connection 447235 for outside:NTP_Server_2/<port> (NTP_Server_2/<port>) to identity:<IP>/<port> (<IP>/<port>)
Dec 11 08:01:24 <IP> %ASA-4-106023: Deny udp src dmz:OCSP_Server/<port> dst outside:DNS_Server_DO/<port> by access-group "dmz" [0x123a465e, 0x4c7bf613]
Dec 11 08:01:24 <IP> %ASA-4-106023: Deny udp src dmz:OCSP_Server/<port> dst outside:DNS_Server_DO/<port> by access-group "dmz" [0x123a465e, 0x4c7bf613]
Dec 11 08:01:31 <IP> %ASA-6-302013: Built outbound TCP connection 447236 for outside:KAV_Update_Server/<port> (KAV_Update_Server/<port>) to dmz:OCSP_Server/<port> (OCSP_Server/<port>)
Dec 11 08:01:31 <IP> %ASA-6-302013: Built outbound TCP connection 447236 for outside:KAV_Update_Server/<port> (KAV_Update_Server/<port>) to dmz:OCSP_Server/<port> (OCSP_Server/<port>)
Dec 11 08:01:31 <IP> %ASA-6-302014: Teardown TCP connection 447236 for outside:KAV_Update_Server/<port> to dmz:OCSP_Server/<port> duration 0:00:00 bytes 14804 TCP FINs
Dec 11 08:01:38 <IP> %ASA-6-302014: Teardown TCP connection 447234 for outside:KAV_Update_Server/<port> to dmz:TSP_Server/<port> duration 0:01:08 bytes 134781 TCP FINs
Dec 11 08:01:38 <IP> %ASA-6-302014: Teardown TCP connection 447234 for outside:KAV_Update_Server/<port> to dmz:TSP_Server/<port> duration 0:01:08 bytes 134781 TCP FINs
Dec 11 08:01:38 <IP> %ASA-6-106015: Deny TCP (no connection) from KAV_Update_Server/<port> to TSP_Server/<port> flags RST  on interface outside
Dec 11 08:01:38 <IP> %ASA-6-106015: Deny TCP (no connection) from KAV_Update_Server/<port> to TSP_Server/<port> flags RST  on interface outside
Dec 11 08:01:39 <IP> %ASA-4-106023: Deny udp src dmz:TSP_Server/<port> dst outside:DNS_Server_DO/<port> by access-group "dmz" [0x123a465e, 0x8c20f21]
Dec 11 08:01:53  %ASA-4-106023: last message repeated 9 times
Dec 11 08:01:53 <IP> %ASA-6-302013: Built outbound TCP connection 447237 for outside:KAV_Update_Server/<port> (KAV_Update_Server/<port>) to dmz:TSP_Server/<port> (TSP_Server/<port>)
Dec 11 08:01:53 <IP> %ASA-6-302013: Built outbound TCP connection 447237 for outside:KAV_Update_Server/<port> (KAV_Update_Server/<port>) to dmz:TSP_Server/<port> (TSP_Server/<port>)
Dec 11 08:01:53 <IP> %ASA-6-302014: Teardown TCP connection 447237 for outside:KAV_Update_Server/<port> to dmz:TSP_Server/<port> duration 0:00:00 bytes 11420 TCP FINs
```

I found only this [doc](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa82/configuration/guide/monitor_syslog.html#wp1082815) from Cisco where nothing explained about "Message_text" field.

Comment: What is your real question?  Your link explains how the ASA creates syslog messages and in what format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at this, use eg %ASA-4-106023 as index :
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa80/system/message/logmsgs.html

Error Message    %PIX|ASA-4-106023: Deny protocol src 
[interface_name:source_address/source_port] dst 
interface_name:dest_address/dest_port [type {string}, code {code}] by 
access_group acl_ID

Explanation    A real IP packet was denied by the ACL. This message displays even if you do not have the log option enabled for an ACL.

Recommended Action    If messages persist from the same source address, messages might indicate a foot-printing or port-scanning attempt. Contact the remote host administrators.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about what the Mnemonics are, there's an explanation [here](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/technologies/collateral/tk869/tk769/white_paper_c11-557812.html#wp9000340).